# Angularjs - selecting element (textarea) and changing its value

Tags: angularjs

can somebody point me out how to do this? None of my solutions work.

I am fairly new to Angularjs, thank you for your patience in advance.

Comment: dude ! paste some code or try to explain little more !

Comment: You seem to have a jquery-ish approach in order to modify you input element, which is quite bad in angularJS paradigm. Just like any input, use ng-model directive attribute and set the $scope from the controller.

Comment: I intentionally did not add any code because I am "jquery-oriented" and I thought there must me some more "angular-oriented" solution as @chandings stated below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
```

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.textAreaValue = "hello World";

```
$scope.textAreaChanged = function(){
    console.log("textAreaChanged new value> " + $scope.textAreaValue);
}

$scope.textAreaBlurred = function(){
    console.log("textAreaBlurred");
}

$scope.textAreaFocussed = function(){
    console.log("textAreaFocussed");
}
```

});

for full code you can go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chandings/qwL0ha63/)

Comment: Thank you @chandings, that fully explains it. Is this called data bind?

Comment: yes we are binding "$scope.textAreaValue "  to ng-model of the text area. ng-model is an inbuilt directive that is used to bind value to various inputs. With angularjs you will be using ng-model alot. ng-change, ng-focus and ng-blur are also inbuilt angular directives.